# Prevent application window from moving

Tags: 16.04

I want to prevent a window from moving (by clicking on title bar and drag). Want it to stay still at one place until it is closed.

Appreciate any help.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you're using KDE/Plasma, you can use the window manager application settings / window settings to control this.

- Click the window icon or right-click in the title bar or use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up a context menu.
- Select "More actions" -> "Special application settings" or "Special window settings".
- There, use the "Position" checkbox to force the window to stay at a specific position.

[image: Application-specific settings]